# Prove that there is a pair of points $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in J$ that has maximal distance in a Jordan curve.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

**strong text**Having proved that a Jordan curve is an arc I want to prove the following:

Prove that there is a pair of points $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in J$ such that $$d(\mathbf{s}, \mathbf{t}) \leq d(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \forall s,t \in J.$$

**My thoughts:**

I know that $J$ is compact and I know that it is an arc and I know that for an arc from a closed interval $[a,b]$ we can identify the 2 endpoints of an arc because we will have a homeomorphism $\bar{\alpha}$ because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Hausdorff. But then I do not know what to do. Could anyone help me in answering this question please?

I have also all those statements of the criss-cross theorem given below and I got a hint to use the criss-cross theorem but I do not know how.

**Criss - Cross Theorem.**

> Let $D$ be a space with a subspace $S\subset D$ such that there is a commutative square
>
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> \partial(I\times I) @>{\cong}>> S\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
> I\times I @>{f}>{\cong}> D
> \end{CD}$$
>
> where the vertical arrows are injections and the horizontal arrows are homeomorphisms. Write $$a_0=f(0,0), a_1=f(1,1), b_0=f(0,1), b_1=f(1,0).$$
>
> Suppose
>
> - $A\subseteq D$ is an arc with endpoints $a_0$ and $a_1$, and
> - $B\subseteq D$ is an arc with endpoints $b_0$ and $b_1$.
>     Then $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.

**Another equivalent statement**

Here is the Criss - Cross theorem statement:

If $\alpha, \beta : I \rightarrow I \times I$ are paths such that $\alpha(0) = (0,0),\alpha(1) = (1,1),$ and $\beta(0) = (0,1),\beta(1) = (1,0).$ Then there are $a,b \in I $ such that $\alpha(a) = \beta(b).$

**And here is a third equivalent statement:**

If $A,B \subseteq I \times I$ are path connected subsets such that $(0,0),(1,1) \in A$ and  $(0,1),(1,0) \in B,$ then $A \cap B \neq \emptyset.$

**Also, I have this lemma (I am allowed to use it but I am not sure how it maybe helpful)**

If $X$ is a metric space and $A \subseteq X,$ then for any point $x \in X$ and any $r > 0,$ we have $$\delta_{A}(B_{r}(x)) \subseteq B_{r}(\delta_{A}(x)).$$

Where $A \subseteq X$ and $\delta_{A}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by the rule $\delta_{A}(x) = \inf\{d(x.a) | a \in A\}$

**Definition:**

A Jordan curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the image $J$ of an injective continuous function $w : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2.$ If $J$ is a Jordan curve with the inclusion map $j : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,$ then there is the following commutative diagram > $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>{w}>> \mathbb{R}^2\\
@VVV @VVV \\
J @>{j}>> \mathbb{R}^2
\end{CD}$$

> The first vertical arrow should have the map $\bar{\omega}$ on it. Also,I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams this is why I draw $\mathbb{R}^2$ 2 times because I do not know how to draw one curved arrow coming out of $J$ going directly to $\mathbb{R}^2$ my bad.

**Definition:**

An arc in a topological space $X$ is a subspace $A \subseteq X$ that is the image of an injective continuous function $\alpha : [a,b] \rightarrow X$ from a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to $X.$ If $X$ is Hausdorff, then the map  $\bar{\alpha} : [a,b] \rightarrow A$ obtained from $\alpha$ by restricting the target is a homeomorphism.

The homeomorphism $\bar{\alpha}$ enables us to identify the two endpoints of an arc $A \subseteq X-$ they are the points $\bar{\alpha}(a)$ and $\bar{\alpha}(b).$

**I was given a hint** to create a continuous function similar to the maximum function but then what?

Comment: Hint: $J\times J$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove a more general result:

Let $A, B$ be two compact subsets of a metric space $(X,d)$. Then there exist $a \in B$ and $b \in B$ such that $d(s,t) \le d(a,b)$ for all $s \in A, t \in B$.

Define $\phi : A \times B \to \mathbb R, \phi(s,t) = d(s,t)$. It is easy to see that $\phi$ is continuous when we regard $A \times B$ as subspace of $X \times X$, where the latter product is endowed with the product topology induced by the product metric $d'((x,y),(x',y')) = \sqrt{d(x,x)^2 + d(y,y')^2}$. Since $A \times B$ is compact, $\phi$ attains a maximum at some $(a,b) \in A \times B$. That proves the above result.